# linear algebra books with many examples

Tags: reference-request

I am looking for books on linear algebra written in English that explain thing clearly and contain many good examples.

I don't possess a very in-depth knowledge of mathematics. Also, it's alright if the book is quite lengthy or pricey.

Please answer not only the title of book but the reason you think it is good.

Comment: You can edit the title and content of your previous post, I would do that, and then delete this post.

Comment: Schaum's Outline - Linear Algebra comes to mind, but you might need a linear algebra book to supplement it, but is it loaded with 3000 problems or so.

Comment: Okay now we know you have at least done calculus.

Comment: Copying and pasting the same *extremely broad* request for book recommendations, each time simply changing the topic, is not appropriate. Voting to close this question, and your others [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/420865/264) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/420882/264).

Comment: @Amzoti why he might need a linear algebra book to supplement it?

Comment: It is akways good to have more than one reference in case matters are not clear and the problem style books are sometimes very short on writeups.

Answer (score 1):

The book by Terry Lawson: [http://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/0471308978/ref=mp_s_a_1_1?qid=1371281089&sr=8-1&pi=SL75](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471308978) is the one I was taught with. I would recommend the solutions manual as well. I looked at the variety and the 6 dollars one is the best bet. Another book that's great is Schaums guide to Linear Algebra. Seen here: [http://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/0071794565/ref=mp_s_a_1_1?qid=1371281395&sr=8-1&pi=SL75](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071794565) The $10 one is the best bet, cheapest. Schaums has a lot of books on many subjects and its what I use to refresh my memory for the Math GRE.

Comment: this book of Terry Lawson has the same style of Schaums?

Comment: No. Schaums is a comprehensive spark notes to go along with any textbook, or as a refresher. Lawson tries to cover all bases by the end of the book from algebraic combinations of matrices, to statistics, to differential equations. It covers all the basics in the first 4 chapters and the outside applications in the last 2.

Answer (score 0):

There are various books which contain linear algebra and explain in a good way.

1.Linear algera and its applications : G. Strang This book has examples and the language is also easy.Its good for begineers.

2.Tom Apostal Calculus Part 2 : It has basics of linear algebra and explains it in a good manner (slightly higher level than strang)If you have done calculus then this is good enough.

1. Linear algebra done right by S.axler : this book is an undergraduate text book.I liked it as its level is good for those who have done basic courses and learn advanced things from it.

Comment: Axler a graduate level text? Pfft yeah right. Everything is over $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ only and I've seen it used for a first course in linear algebra.